# Add an Azure AD user to a Azure DevOps project group using Azure Logic Apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to add an Azure AD user to an Azure DevOps project group using the Azure Logic Apps DevOps Connector, action **Send an HTTP request to Azure DevOps** but I receive status **Unauthorized** while with the same user I am able to do it manually in the portal. Because there is almost no documentation regarding this tool and APIs it's using, I guess it is something with the URI but not sure. Any ideas?

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I understood from [Choosing the right authentication mechanism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/authentication-guidance?view=azure-devops) that the service principals are not supported and ordered for my App Registration 
user_impersonation API Permission scope for Azure DevOps. Hopefully this will provide me a token authorised to do this. If you have useful links on obtaining the token different than mentioned above, please share. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, Would you mind adding an Azure AD user to a Azure DevOps project group in other ways? Such as power shell script?

Comment: Hi, I have shared the power shell script, please check the update1

Comment: Yeah, I am doing it with a PAT as a workaround. It is not so convenient as the logic app connector + it can be issued for max 1 year. Thanks for the PS example below.

Comment: Hi, If this answer is helpful, would you please [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) as the answer? So it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread. Thanks. Have a nice day. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could not add an Azure AD user to a Azure DevOps project group via Azure Logic Apps. This is an known issue in the action **Send an HTTP request to Azure DevOps**

We are using this REST API to [add an AAD user as member of a group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/users/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#add-an-aad-user-as-member-of-a-group), it need the [permission scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/users/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#security) `vso.graph_manage`

And according to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/visualstudioteamservices/#known-issues-and-limitations) Action Send an HTTP request to Azure DevOps has a limited set of scopes which control what resources can be accessed by the action and what operations the action is allowed to perform on those resources.

The Scopes contain:

- vso.agentpools_manage
- vso.build_execute
- vso.chat_manage
- vso.code_manage
- vso.code_status
- vso.connected_server
- vso.dashboards_manage
- vso.entitlements
- vso.extension.data_write
- vso.extension_manage
- vso.identity
- vso.loadtest_write
- vso.packaging_manage
- vso.project_manage
- vso.release_manage
- vso.test_write
- vso.work_write

Since it does not contain the scope `vso.graph_manage`, and we could see the error message : `TF400813: The user xxx is not authorized to access this resource` in the output content

**Update1**

Power shell script:

```
$connectionToken="{PAT}"
$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))
$URL = "https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{Org name}/_apis/graph/users?groupDescriptors={groupDescriptors}&api-version=6.0-preview.1" 

$body =@"
{
  "principalName": "{User email}"
}
"@
$Result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URL -ContentType "application/json" -Body $body -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Method POST
```